How to have driver be affected by multiple custom properties
I have an armature with two custom properties and I would like an object to be hidden if either property is turned in. Is it possible to have a driver work for both custom properties?

Yes.

Create the driver on the render visibility of the object (the camera icon next to it in the outliner).
Make sure the driver type is "Scripted Expression".
Rename the single default input variable "var" to "p1" or something without a space.
Set the Prop ID Type of the input variable to "Object" if it isn't already (it probably is). You do this by clicking whatever icon is on the left of the field next to the word "Prop:"
Pick the armature object as the input object for the property. Note that in the screenshot below this would be where “Your Object” is.
Set the Path RNA to ["first prop's name here"].
Add a new Input Variable, and repeat steps 3-6, but with a name like "p2" and the second prop's name for the RNA instead.
Set the script field to p1 or p2, substituting whatever you named the in put variables.

The result should look something like this:

